# ExtJS charts into jQuery UI tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to put an ExtJS chart into a jquery UI tab... the simple code is this

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {
 Ext.create('Ext.chart.CartesianChart', {
     renderTo: 'binding-example',
     deferredRender: false,
     width: 600,
     height: 200,
     store: {
         fields: ['name', 'g1', 'g2'],
         data: [
             { "name": "Item-0", "g1": 57, "g2": 59 },
             { "name": "Item-1", "g1": 45, "g2": 50 },
             { "name": "Item-2", "g1": 67, "g2": 43 },
             { "name": "Item-3", "g1": 45, "g2": 18 },
             { "name": "Item-4", "g1": 30, "g2": 90 }

         ]
     },

     legend: {
         docked: 'bottom'
     },

     //define x and y axis.
     axes: [{
         type: 'numeric',
         position: 'left'
     }, {
         type: 'category',
         visibleRange: [0, 1],
         position: 'bottom'
     }],

     //define the actual series
     series: [{
         type: 'line',
         xField: 'name',
         yField: 'g1',
         title: 'Normal'
     }, {
         type: 'line',
         xField: 'name',
         yField: 'g2',
         title: 'Smooth'
     }]
 });
```

});

and the html is this:

```
       <div id="mytabs">
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>tab01</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#fragment-2"><span>tab02</span></a></li>    
    </ul>
    <div id="fragment-1">
<div id="first_tab"></div>
</div>
    <div id="fragment-2">
    <div id="binding-example"> </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {    

        jQuery('#mytabs').tabs(); });
    </script>
```

when I change the code:
renderTo:document.body
or
renderTo:'first_tab'
I can make the chart render properly according to this 

[link to the unaltered example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/extjs/linechart.htm)

¿is there a method in ExtJS or in JQuery UI tabs that render properly?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: well... it's just loading all things sweet...  but for no reason when loading ExtJS-all.js now it's just warning me this:
unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]

Comment: but i have another ExtJS component with a JQuery UI tabs also...and it's giving me that trivial thing when the component is quite complex...

Comment: i didnt realize this error since i've just loaded a chart into the new layout... i  have done a component but it's showing first... and i read about that it will render when the tab is active... but i think there should be a way... i'm putting the JS at the end of the document...

Comment: Move your  jQuery('#mytabs').tabs(); inside Ext.onReady and let's see what happens. No need for 2 ready event listeners

Comment: ok... so i've just did what you suggest it's showing but the animation effect is not working properly and i have to click on it in order to show up... and it's more likely an image a static png... looks like a png instead of a Extjs chart...

Comment: so i 've just made a work around by doing a callback function when the tab is selected... the rudimentary way i found is by looking through the dom and insert it a click... it's quite messy but it works:
`jQuery("#tab2").on("click", function() {
        panelInsideExtjs();
    });`
if you have a different opnion it's good... what i did it's quite simple indeed... just made a simple function for the chart insted of making a setTimeout... it's working but i think it'll not in another PC not so fast

Comment: I am glad that you figured it out